# Why does the following Java 8 pipeline report a type mismatch in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

The following code uses Java 8 streams and lambdas to find an unlimited number of "sum primes" :

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FunctionalPrime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printSumPrimes(6);
    }

    /**
     * Given n>0, print all pairs i & j s.t. 1<=i<=j<=n and i+j is prime
     *
     * NOTE: This BREAKS in Eclipse because of some Eclipse bug!
     * I had to compile it on the command-line using javac. 
     *
     * @param n
     */
    public static void printSumPrimes(int n) {
        Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1)
                .limit(n)
                .flatMap(
                        i -> Stream.iterate(1, j -> j + 1).limit(n)
                                .filter(j -> i <= j)
                                .map(j -> new int[] { i, j }))
                // .forEach(pair -> System.out.println("" + pair[0] + " " +
                // pair[1]));
                .filter(pair -> isPrime(pair[0] + pair[1]))
                .forEach(
                        pair -> System.out.println("" + pair[0] + " + "
                                + pair[1] + " = " + (pair[0] + pair[1])
                                + " is prime"));
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        return  Stream.iterate(2, i -> i + 1)
            .limit((long) Math.sqrt(n))
            .noneMatch(i -> n % i == 0);
    }
}
```

Eclipse 4.4.2 (BuildId 20150219-0600) reports the following compile-time error :

- The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object

And yet the same code runs fine on the command-line :

[image: Command-Line Compiles and Runs]

What's going on? ...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is going on. There have been similar questions about problems with long Stream pipelines before, but I am not aware that people tried it on the command line also. 
The problem is, that in some situations the compiler does not have enough information to infer the type(s). The trick is, to give more inforamtion in one or the other way. For you problem, this works:

```
public static void printSumPrimes(int n) {

    Stream<Integer> intstream = Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).limit(n);

    Stream<int[]> intarraystream = intstream.flatMap(i -> Stream
            .iterate(1, j -> j + 1).limit(n).filter(j -> i <= j)
            .map(j -> new int[] { i, j }));

    intarraystream
        .filter(pair -> isPrime(pair[0] + pair[1]))
        .forEach(pair -> output(pair));
}


private static void output(final int[] pair) {
    System.out.println(String.format(
             "%1$s + %2$s = %3$s is prime", 
             pair[0], pair[1], pair[0] + pair[1])
    );
}
```